# Can I attach a plain DataSource to a document on Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

I have a Bokeh server running and I am embeding it as a Bokeh document in my application, this allows me to change a glyph data source from a component in my front end (while having the sockets connection) by accessing it like:

```
let mySource = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('mySource');
...
(alter the data)
...
mySource.change.emit();
```

However my problem is that this source needs to be the source of a glyph, for it to be accessible in Bokeh.documents[0] through my front end components. But I want this datasource just to be an empty list, and add "ids" through the front end, and then in python get the **data** for those IDs which is going to be the bokeh glyph source.

The problem, I can not find a way to attach a plain datasource into the bokeh root. I only can get a datasource in there as part of a glyph (But I do not need a glyph for a list of ids).

Does anyone has some advice regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ColumnDataSource` to a glyph or to a data table and hide it using `visible` attribute. See example with `DataTable` and empty `ColumnDataSource` below (works for Bokeh v2.1.1):

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn

columns=[TableColumn(field=str(i),title=str(i),width=200,name=str(i)) for i in range(2)]
source = ColumnDataSource(data={}, name='mySource')
table=DataTable(source=source,columns=columns,name='myTable',visible=False)
curdoc().add_root(table)
```