# Bokeh: Failed to trigger js_on_change on ColumnDataSource from doc.add_periodic_callback()

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to update Slope y_intercept from another thread in bokeh server. But I can not trigger js_on_change, it seems the javascript code is not even generated. Could someone let me what's wrong here? This is the whole code (updated to use add_periodic_callback()):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slope, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server
import pandas as pd

source = ColumnDataSource()
n = 0

def update():
    global n
    source.data = pd.DataFrame({"y": [n]})
    print(f"{source.data=}")
    n += 1

def bkapp(doc):
    plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10))
    plot.line([-10, 10], [-10, 10])
    slope = Slope(gradient=0, y_intercept=0, line_color='black')
    plot.add_layout(slope)

    source.js_on_change('data', CustomJS(
        args=dict(ds=source, slopes=slope), code="""
        console.log("whereismycode");
        slope.y_intercept = ds.data["y"][0];
        """
        ))

    doc.add_root(plot)
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 5000)

server = Server({'/': bkapp}, port=5103, num_procs=1)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'address = {server.address}, port = {server.port}')

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

Comment: If you want `update` to keep happening on a fixed interval, then Bokeh's built-in `add_periodic_callback` seems like a better choice. Otherwise you will need to go though the process described at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads where the thread calls `add_next_tick_callback`.

Comment: @bigreddot, i updated the code, issue is the same

Comment: You have added `plot` as the document root, but where have you told it that `source` is part of the document?  How would it know to watch it?  Is that Bokeh magic I don't understand?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'm confused about this part as well, how can I tell bokeh this data source should be used in a doc without using it in the python code ? (but use it only in javascript)

Comment: using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683190/can-i-attach-a-plain-datasource-to-a-document-on-bokeh, i get the callback triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely based on the question, *exactly as presented above*, no CDS is necessary at all in order to update the slope, and adding one is an over-complication. Here is the code I would write:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slope
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server

n = 0

def bkapp(doc):
    plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10))
    plot.line([-10, 10], [-10, 10])
    slope = Slope(gradient=0, y_intercept=0, line_color='black')
    plot.add_layout(slope)

    def update():
        global n
        slope.y_intercept = n
        n += 1

    doc.add_root(plot)
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 5000)

server = Server({'/': bkapp}, port=5103, num_procs=1)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'address = {server.address}, port = {server.port}')

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

As an aside, note that if you expect at all to have more than one user/session at a time, then there cannot be any "global" Bokeh models (e.g. like the global CDS in your case). The `bkapp` function must return an *entirely unique and new set of objects* for each session.

Comment: ah, didn't realize python object and javascript object is automatically synchronized!

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code. as Tim Roberts pointed out, the issue is that bokeh doc doesn't know about the data source. A hacky solution is to attached it to a hidden glyph. @bigreddot, maybe there's a special method just for this purpose ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slope, CustomJS, DataTable
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd

source = ColumnDataSource()
n = 0

def update():
    global n
    source.data = pd.DataFrame({"y": [n]})
    print(f"{source.data=}")
    n += 1

def bkapp(doc):
    plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10))
    plot.line([-10, 10], [-10, 10])
    slope = Slope(gradient=0, y_intercept=0, line_color='black')
    plot.add_layout(slope)

    table = DataTable(source=source, visible=False)

    source.js_on_change('data', CustomJS(
        args=dict(ds=source, slope=slope), code="""
        console.log("whereismycode");
        slope.y_intercept = ds.data["y"][0];
        """
        ))

    doc.add_root(column([plot, table]))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 5000)

server = Server({'/': bkapp}, port=5103, num_procs=1)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'address = {server.address}, port = {server.port}')

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

Comment: You shoud be able to pass a `DataModel` subclass in `args` but even that should not be necessary (see above) unless the question is missing important requirements.